# How to use k_means algorithms on likert dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, python, k-means, jupyter

I have a dataset of 10,000 customers with ten features all of which are Likert type. Like this:

| customer | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | 3 | 1 | 5 |
| ID2 | 4 | 5 | 4 |
| ID3 | 3 | 5 | 1 |
| ID4 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| ID5 | 2 | 5 | 1 |
| ID6 | 1 | 3 | 4 |

I want to use K_mean for clustering this database in python. I use:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler=MinMaxScaler()
data_normal=scaler.fit_transform(data)
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

k=4
model = KMeans(n_clusters=k)
pred=model.fit_predict(data_normal)
```

1. What should I do after these steps for interpreting my results?
2. And if I want to see the features in each cluster, what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I don't know the precise way to do that with python but the main idea is that you should probably use the **centroids*** of the clusters as the representative point of the cluster. Also I don't think you need to use scaling with likert scores since they are all on a standard range of values.

Comment: @Erwan, Thanks for your response.